# Square brackets in POST request

Tags: php, forms

Let's say I have a `form.html` that looks like this:

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="submitted[name]">
Age: <input type="text" name="age">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

And a `welcome.php` that looks like this:

```
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["submitted[name]"]; ?>!<br>
You are <?php echo $_POST["age"]; ?> years old.
```

Why is the age displaying but not the name? I'm sure it's the square brackets. I **can't** change the name of the variable `submitted[name]`

I tried putting `\, "` but didn't work. What's the trick?

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: Try `$_POST["submitted"]["name"];`

Comment: simply change this: `name="submitted[name]"` to this `name="username"` and in your php `$_POST['username']`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

Answer (score 7):

The square brackets on the name attribute will post an array to PHP try accessing it using `$_POST['submited']['name']`

Answer (score 3):

The square brackets in your HTML form turn it into an array.  `$_POST["submitted"]` is an array.

You want to read:

```
$_POST["submitted"]["name"];
```